# Could someone give examples of upward communication between a LAYERED ARCHITECTURE?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm reading the Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software book and at the beginning of Part II the author talks about upward communication and how it can be achieved. However, I didn't get what this means, I would like to know about some more examples of this upward communication. For instance, a communication that starts at the INFRASTRUCTURE level when I have the following LAYERS: UI -> Application -> Services -> Domain -> Infrastructure.

Comment: Thats kinda off-topic on Stack Overflow, which is for programming related question and ones that can be answered definitely. That would be more suitable on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) StackExchange

Comment: Ok, sorry. We have this `domain-driven-design` tag here, I don't think a question with this tag can be answered definitely. Anyway, is it possible to move this question or something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what book you are refering to, but the books I know usually prefer an architecture with toppled layers, or hexagonal.

Consider the following layering (source code dependencies):

`UI -> Application/Domain <- Infrastructure`

Notice how the dependencies point inwards to your application "core". If this confuses you,  the technique employed here is the "Dependency Inversion Principle" - separation of highlevel policies (application/domain) and lowlevel implementations (infra).

In this case it would be no problem to have scheduled jobs or something like that which invoke some application service since infrastruction is "allowed" to access logic offered by your core.

I am not sure if this is what you had in mind, but in general the following applies to DDD layering: the infra layer in DDD offers implementations to ALL infrastrucure related interfaces in ALL layers an thus can be seen as a somewhat "sourrounding" outer layer.

Comment: Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software.

Comment: I don't now how I could miss that, but could you evaluate the answer? Toppled layers are considered idiomatic DDD (Vaughn Vernon, etc.) and allow exactly what you require: business operations triggered by infrastructure

Comment: But I would like to know which actions would the architecture layer initiate and how it is going to happen. The example in the book is about sending an e-mail, but only this example wasn't enough for me to understand.

Comment: Just think about a scheduled task for example. In the infrastructure layer there could be residing a `CronNotificationScheduler` which has an instance of the applications `UserNotifier` and triggers notifications say, once per day, via the Notifiers methods. Clear?

Comment: Yes, kind of. But this could be implemented in the Service layer too, right? This way the communication continues to be downwards. Is there anything you can imagine that could only be implemented in the `Infrastructure` layer?